# wpf custom control using blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, blend, togglebutton

I'm trying to build a custom `ToggleIconButton` with image = toggle button with image.
But some features as `Command` not really working.

I created the following custom class:

```
public class ToggleIconButton : ToggleButton
{
    static ToggleIconButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ToggleIconButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToggleIconButton)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string), typeof(ToggleIconButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Icon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and using `Blend`, I created the following style:

`ResourceDictionary1.xaml`

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonHoverBorder" Color="#3399FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonChecked" Color="#E6F0FA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonHover" Color="#C2E0FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonPressedBorder" Color="#3399FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarButtonPressed" Color="#99CCFF"/>
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Image Width="22" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:ToggleIconButton}}}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHoverBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonChecked}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHoverBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHoverBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonHover}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressedBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressed}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressedBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressed}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressedBorder}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonPressed}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ToggleIconButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ToggleIconButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ToggleIconButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="Click!" Style="{DynamicResource ContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}"/>
```

and apply the custom control:

```
<ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Controls:ToggleIconButton 
        Content="ToggleIconButton" 
        Height="24" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ToggleIconButtonStyle}" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Width="24"
        Icon="/Images/musicNote48.png"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
        />
```

The control shown good, with the icon, but Command is not invoked. If i click on the ContentPresenter content it is... my wish is to remove the `ContentPresenter` with the label "Click!" and use only the icon...

Comment: I have created a custom toggle button much along the line of yours, but I opted to notify the VM by synching up the IsChecked property.  This works totally fine, have you considered that approach?  If you need a sample snippet as an 'answer' just shout.

Comment: You extended a ToggleButton, making your own custom implementation and altered its ControlTemplate. Then you are writing one more style in which you are setting already created Style to another ToggleButton and then you are using this Style for your Custom ToggleButton again. Why so ?

Comment: Gary i would love to.

Comment: Nitesh, i think i need two style. 
one for the ToggleButton and another one to mine.
unless i can do it with only one... but when i do "Make into Control", Blend automatically creates another style.
would appreciate to have an example with one custom toggle button.

Comment: @kaycee, as requested a working snippet is provided...